# Meaning of $\frac{\| {PA - LU} \|_{F}}{\| {A} \|_F}$ and $\frac{\| {PA - LU} \|_F}{\| {L}\|_F \| {U} \|_F}.$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm studying PLU decomposition and in one of the problem I was asked to implement the algorithm in MATLAB, then report $\frac{\| {PA - LU} \|_{F}}{\| {A} \|_F}$ and $\frac{\| {PA - LU} \|_F}{\| {L}\|_F \| {U} \|_F}$ for the following matrices: $hilb(5), hilb(10), hilb(20)$, where $hilb(n)$ is an $n\times n$ Hilbert matrix. I've implemented the algorithm and I know how to compute these expressions, but I wonder what do they mean. I believe that $\frac{\| {PA - LU} \|_{F}}{\| {A} \|_F}$ is the relative error of the algorithm, and I also found out in the article on google that it's the 'backward error'. From what I understand "backward error relates to the rounding errors in the computation to the errors in the data $x$, rather than $f(x).$" It's a little bit confusing, can someone explain the meaning and differences for me?

EDIT: I got the following results of $\frac{\| {PA - LU} \|_F}{\| {L}\|_F \| {U} \|_F}$ for $hilb(5), hilb(10), hilb(20)$ respectively: $7.7816e{-18}, 1.4567e{-18}, 4.3902e{-20}$. We can see that the values are decreasing.
As for $\frac{\| {PA - LU} \|_F}{\| {A} \|_F}$ we have $2.4829e{-17}, 3.0352e{-17}, 4.8843e-{17}$. These values on the other hand are increasing.